Better traction between bolt & coupling nuts
I need some M10 coupling nuts to fasten with my M10 1.5mm pitched bolts. Either I order the coupling nuts online or I weld together M10 ordinary nuts together until I have the right length.
Going about welding them, if one is to twist 2 ordinary nuts while in a bolt towards each other to really close the clearance for welding them together, the nuts really grips on the bolt thread.

Is the extra traction only happening on the first threads between the 2 nuts or is it applied more or less evenly along their whole threads? Is this a good way to get better traction between the bolt & the nuts, without resorting to a finer pitch? Is this an interchangeable solution? That is, would any other M10 1.5mm pitched bolt be swappable here? What are the downsides?

So, depending on the load I would look at steel tube with a tapped thread which you can choose the grade as necessary.
